# Understanding AMPScript Help

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Someone else created the below AMPScript and im trying to understand what it is doing, I think i am pretty close however it would be good to have someone who understands AMPScript to confirm

I have put `/*` `*/`  around what i think it is doing and any questions as i don't understand what it's doing

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");  /* what does this mean? */

try {

</script>

%%[

var @de, @mob, @lookup
set @mob = MOBILE_NUMBER  /* @Mob is short Mobile_Number field  */
set @de = "SampleRequestLinkSent"  /* @de is short for the data extension SampleRequestLinkSent  */
set @lookup = Lookup(@de,'Locale','MobileNumber', @mob) /* Does this look up mobile number from the data extension SampleRequestLinkSent? */

if Empty(@lookup) /* If there is no mobile number follow the next steps or move to ##{Else}##    */

    UpsertData(@de,1, 'MobileNumber',@mob,'Locale', 'NZ','SampleRequested','False','MobileContact', @mob) /* Either update record if match found or insert new record and set the field Locale to NZ, SampleRequested to False, mobile number to Mobile contact field what does the ,1 mean after @de? */

    UpsertData('AnmumOptIn',1, 'MobileNumber',@mob,'Locale', 'NZ','OptedInAnmum','True') /* Same process as above just in different DE, */

]%%

---- Sends this message
Thanks, great to hear from you

%%[ else ]%% 
--- Thanks, great to hear from you

%%[endif]%%

<script type="text/javascript" runat=server>

} catch(e) {

Write('Sorry, there was an error. Please try again.');

}
</script>
```

Comment: The SSJS try/catch around an AMPscript block is a method for trapping runtime errors.  It doesn't appear necessary in your case.  The only thing that'd cause a runtime error would be if the script executed when `MOBILE_NUMBER` didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This MobileConnect script retrieves the locale for a mobile number. If the locale doesn't exist, it adds or updates a record in two data extensions -- `SampleRequestLinkSent` and `AnmumOptIn`

The SSJS try/catch doesn't appear to be necessary, but you are missing an `THEN` in your `IF` statement.  I'd write it like this:

```
%%[

    var @de, @mob, @locale
    set @mob = AttributeValue("MOBILE_NUMBER")
    set @de = "SampleRequestLinkSent"  
    set @locale = Lookup(@de, 'Locale', 'MobileNumber', @mob) 

    if empty(@locale) then 

        UpsertData(@de, 1, 'MobileNumber', @mob, 'Locale', 'NZ', 'SampleRequested', 'False', 'MobileContact', @mob)
        UpsertData('AnmumOptIn', 1, 'MobileNumber', @mob, 'Locale', 'NZ', 'OptedInAnmum', 'True') 

    endif 
]%%
Thanks, great to hear from you
```

**Reference**

- [**Lookup**](https://ampscript.guide/book/lookup/)
- [**UpsertData**](https://ampscript.guide/book/upsertdata/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: This is AMPScript inside Server-Side JavaScript (SSJS).

This part is Server-side JavaScript. The function `Platform.Load("Core","1");` "initializes" Server-side JavaScript. On the bottom you find the description: [**SSJS Syntax Guide**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_syntaxGuide.htm).

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");

try {
</script>

<!-- HERE IS ALL YOUR AMPSCRIPT -->

<script type="text/javascript" runat=server>

} catch(e){

Write('Sorry, there was an error. Please try again.');

}
</script>
```

Here are my comments:

```
%%[

var @de, @mob, @lookup

/* @mob is the variable that stores Mobile_Number... */
/* but here is a syntax error either it is "Mobile_Number" or [Mobile_Number] */
set @mob = MOBILE_NUMBER 

/* @de is the variable that stores the text "SampleRequestLinkSent" */
set @de = "SampleRequestLinkSent"  

/* Looks up the "Locale" Field of the mobile number in the data extension "SampleRequestLinkSent". */
/* It is not the mobile number */
set @lookup = Lookup(@de,'Locale','MobileNumber', @mob) 

if Empty(@lookup)

    /* if the Locale field for that number is empty or the data extension doesn't contain it go in this area */
    UpsertData(@de,1, 'MobileNumber',@mob,'Locale', 'NZ', 'SampleRequested', 'False', 'MobileContact', @mob)
    UpsertData('AnmumOptIn',1, 'MobileNumber',@mob,'Locale', 'NZ','OptedInAnmum','True') 

]%%
    ---- Sends this message
    Thanks, great to hear from you

%%[else]%% 
    --- Thanks, great to hear from you
%%[endif]%%
```

**Reference**

- [**Lookup**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm)
- [**UpsertData**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm)

Comment: `MOBILE_NUMBER` is the correct syntax.  Reference: [**Mobile Connect Data Strings**](https://ampscript.guide/book/mobileconnect-data-strings/)